# I have a Japanese maple for a couple of years however it seems to be dying?

Tags: japanese-maple

I bought an acer palmatum a few years ago and it recently looks like its dying. We moved it from its pot to a bed on advice but now it’s very brittle it seemed to grow but now the leaves have curled up. It it a problem with soil sun or shade?

Comment: What part of the world are you  in and how long ago did you plant it in the ground? A photo would be helpful too, if possible...

Comment: Many *Acer palmatum* need shade and leaves die when put in full sun. I had that with a red one. So it would be helpful if you give more information about what kind you have an how much direct sunlight it gets.

Answer (score 0):

yes, could be: Maples are very sensitive: maybe try compare the exact conditions & if theyre different, try get them back as they were; the soil coud be wrong, has a vehicle driven close to it and crushed the roots, ants, water, many possibilities, and likely a combination; if its still possible maybe replace it into the conter,with the same location & soil, or maybe a little bigger container, and check the root health.

Answer (score 0):

Try seaweed fertilizer to help roots and gently feed it in addition to everything above..also remember ground soil and potting soil dry at different rates, whats the moisture like on a meter? Are you still watering on the same schedule as before? Is the soil getting dry between waterings? Maybe its too dry?these are from Japanese forests.. do the leaves yellow and fall off or just curl get crispy and fall off?